# c++ socket programming with url:port/url in getaddrinfo

Tags: c++, sockets, getaddrinfo

Relearning C++ and fairly new to sockets. I have a Python app that connects properly and a .NET app that works.

The URL I need to call is `domain.com:8080/signalr`. I'm following what seems to be a [standard example](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html#simpleserver), e.g.:

```
if ((rv = getaddrinfo("www.domain.com", PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
```

...but no matter what I try, I get *name or service unknown*.

- Calling `domain.com/signalr:8080` will not work.
- I tried leaving PORT null

This is running on Raspbian (Debian) if that matters.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 8080 goes in the port param.  Browsers do that for you, not getaddrinfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `getaddrinfo()` does is name resolution. It does not implement the HTTP protocol. Also, it does not know how to parse the URL, you have to do that yourself.

The right call would be something along the lines of:

```
getaddrinfo("www.Domain.com", "8080", ...);
```

And that will return the right `struct sockaddr*` to call `connect()` and do all the socket stuff.

If you want a function that does all the HTTP protocol for you, you'll need a higher level library. I recommend [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: I understand it doesn't implement the HTTP protocol, unfortunately I can't easily change the URL to be called (not even sure if I can). I have used libcurl a little, are you saying I can somehow integrate that with getaddrinfo to be able to call the correct url?

Comment: @VirtualLife: No, `getaddrinfo()` calls nowhere, it just solves the host name and gives you the IP address. Well, it calls DNS, but that doesn't count. What I don't understand is why you insist on using `getaddrinfo()` with a URL, that will never work.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess I was misunderstanding what it did. I thought it was the piece that built the connection, but I guess not. I will do some more research on it. Thanx for your help.

Comment: Can do it like this too (manually) http://ideone.com/lAovHH  Just needs proper checks for reading/writing.