# Calling socket::connect, socket::bind, socket::listen without using getaddrinfo( ) function before it

Tags: c++, sockets, getaddrinfo, endianness

In all the example including [Beej's Guide](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfoman), the IP address is provided in dot notation and then it's fed to `::getaddrinfo()`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572645/c-socket-programming-with-urlport-url-in-getaddrinfo) doesn't answer my question.

After which the `addrinfo` struct is used for socket related functions (e.g. `connect()`, `bind()`, `listen()`). For example:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
// ... create socket etc.
connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
```

[Example](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#connect)
The variable `ai_addr` is of type `sockaddr` which can be **safely** typecasted to `sockaddr_storage`, `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`.

**Question**:

If I typecast `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in` (or `sockaddr_in6`)

```
sockaddr_in& ipv4 = (sockaddr_in&)(sockaddr_variable);
```

and feed below info:

- ipv4.sin_family = AF_INET
- ipv4.sin_addr = [IP Address in net byte order]
- ipv4.sin_port = [Port number in net byte order]

**Can I call the `connect()` method directly using above info?**

```
connect(sockfd, &ipv4, sizeof(ipv4));
```

With my program it doesn't appear to work. Am I missing something, or is there a better way?

The motivation behind is that, if we have the information of IPAddress, Port etc. in socket readable format then why to go through the cycle of `getaddrinfo()`

Comment: sin_addr & sin_port should have the values in network byte order. Do use the function htonl & htons to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you're placing your values in network order, here's a small example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // 173.194.32.207 is a google address
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = 173 | 194 << 8 | 32 << 16 | 207 << 24;
    server.sin_port = 0x5000; // port 80

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connected\n");

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was indeed in network byte order. Due to `<>` in the question, it got disappeared. I have replaced that with `[]`. However your answer suggests that it's possible, which means, I might be making a mistake.

Comment: The code up there is a fully compilable example, so without any other code from your end / actual values you're using we can't be sure what the problem is.

Comment: htons() and htonl() allow portable conversion to network byte order. This will matter when you port your code to a future processor architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the machine is reachable & the server application is running on the machine using "netstat" utility. Use inet_aton method to convert dotted address to network byte order. Finally, log the error value returned by the connect to get the exact reason of failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that calling `socket::{connect, bind, ...}` is wrong: these are `C API`s and C doesn't have namespaces, classes and so on.

You should use `getaddrinfo` as it's much easier and safer to use. But nothing prevents you from using `struct sockaddr` and all its variants. Indeed, `getaddrinfo` is a sort of wrapper as stated in `man(3) getaddrinfo`:

> The  getaddrinfo() function combines the functionality
>          provided by the gethostbyname(3) and getservbyname(3) functions  into  a
>          single  interface,  but  unlike  the  latter functions, getaddrinfo() is
>          reentrant and allows programs to  eliminate  IPv4-versus-IPv6  dependen‐
>          cies.

An example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
   struct sockaddr_in addr = {0};
   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port   = htons(80);

  inet_pton(addr.sin_family, "198.252.206.16", &addr.sin_addr);

  int fd = socket(addr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (fd == -1)
       ; /* could not create socket */

  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        ;  /* could not connect */

   close(fd);

}
```